# Button's FlatStyle Is System When Hovering But Standard When Clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've seen a lot of forms like settings/options forms of Windows where a Button's FlatStyle is System when the mouse if hovering over the button. But when you click the button, the FlatStyle is changed to Standard. This can be found on the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons of Windows's Skype's Option form.

By the way, I would like the code to be written in C#, as I am using C# for my project.

I've tried a few things to make this happen, but it has never worked.

If you are on Windows but don't have Skype, then you can find what I'm talking about in lots of Windows's setting forms—like Windows's "Playback Devices" form.

You can also notice that this doesn't happen to a button if the selected tab is the button itself.

It would be great to have to code/examples to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wire up an event handler for the buttons click and MouseHover events like the following code. And then use the FlatStyle class to change the appearance:

```
  private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
        }
```

Hope this helps you! If it does mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately, I've tried before the same code that you have, and it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Bubbled86 What does it not do?

Comment: I think my question was a little bit different to what I was trying to ask. It does have the appearance of System when you hover over it, but it doesn't have the Standard look until you've let go of the mouse button (MouseUp). Normally with applications that have what I'm talking about, you can notice it turns to Standard FlatStlye when before you let go of the mouse button (left click). But currently it doesn't turn Standard until you completely let go of the mouse button.

Comment: @Bubbled86 So use the MouseDown event, then.

Comment: I've tried the MouseDown event before and tried again just then. But it seems to be very quickly deleting the button the then re-appearing it again.

Answer (score 0):

What u need is MouseEnter instead of MouseHover, so use this:

```
 private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
 }

 private void button1_Down(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
 }
```

To debug:

```
 int i = 0;
 private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
    i++;
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
 }

 private void button1_Down(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
 }
```

Comment: If you trace the number of MouseHover event occur, u should notice that it occurs twice (hence revert the style of button) :
1. first time when u move mouse into the button
2. second time when u click the button, mouse hover occurs again

Comment: I've used the same code you have, but the button disappears when I click it.

Comment: disappears? are u sure u use MouseEnter instead of MouseHover?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I used MouseEnter instead of MouseHover.

Comment: so what do u mean by disappear? using MouseEnter yield same result as using MouseHover?

Comment: Well actually, when the first click has happened to the button, the button refreshes itself.

Comment: Did u delete the MouseHover event?
In my code:
when mouse pointer move into button, button will change to System style->after mouse down, button change to Standard style immediately.
There is no way for button to reset/refresh back to System style unless you accidentally set it in other event.

Comment: If you had confirmed there is no other events trying to set the button style, then the only reason is MouseEnter event had triggered twice. Try my updated code again and see what is the output on console, the result should be 1.